# Is there a way to modify value of FD_SETSIZE (WinSock) in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

Is there any way to increment value of [`FD_SETSIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (WinSock) in Delphi 7 application ?

In C++ I can define it before using `include`, but for Delphi it is impossible.

Comment: When looking at other environments, there is no consensus if this is a wise idea, and it is hard in other environments to change too: https://www.google.com/search?q=FD_SETSIZE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined as a constant, so the only option is to modify this value directly in `WinSock.pas`.

[image]